# Excel SUMPRODUCT/COUNTIFS #DIV/0 Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data where I'm trying to SUM `charge` (all of them) and divide it by the SUM of `num_persons` BUT only SUM `num_persons` when another column, `res_num`, hasn't appeared already on that `date`.

Here's my data (I've changed duplicate res numbers to easier to spot out numbers):

```
     A         B        C         D          E
1    acct_mgr  charge   res_num   date       num_persons
2    johnd     170      62570     6/1/2018   1
3    johnd     140      74001     6/1/2018   1
4    johnd     140      74003     6/1/2018   1
5    johnd     135      74006     6/1/2018   1
6    johnd     195      74008     6/1/2018   1
7    johnd     140      74019     6/1/2018   1
8    johnd     75       74021     6/1/2018   1
9    johnd     140      74027     6/1/2018   1
10   johnd     140      74032     6/1/2018   1
11   johnd     135      74657     6/1/2018   1
12   johnd     85       74662     6/1/2018   1
13   johnd     140      74665     6/1/2018   1
14   johnd     75       11111     6/1/2018   2
15   johnd     75       11111     6/1/2018   2
16   johnd     135      77134     6/1/2018   1
17   johnd     140      77198     6/1/2018   1
18   johnd     75       79546     6/1/2018   1
19   johnd     100      22222     6/1/2018   1
20   johnd     135      22222     6/1/2018   1
21   johnd     135      33333     6/1/2018   1
22   johnd     140      33333     6/1/2018   1
23   johnd     100      44444     6/1/2018   2
24   johnd     140      44444     6/1/2018   2
25   johnd     140      80895     6/1/2018   1
26   johnd     140      81327     6/1/2018   1
27   johnd     140      82025     6/1/2018   1
28   johnd     75       83577     6/1/2018   1
29   johnd     140      83749     6/1/2018   1
30   johnd     170      83814     6/1/2018   1
31   johnd     170      83817     6/1/2018   1
32   johnd     75       55555     6/1/2018   2
33   johnd     140      55555     6/1/2018   2
34   johnd     140      51008     6/2/2018   1
...
```

So with this example data on `6/1/2018` - `charge` is 4075 and `num_persons` is 30, making my answer `135.83`.

If I use a formula I was given (`=SUMPRODUCT(E2:E33/COUNTIFS(A2:A33,H2,D2:D33,H3,E2:E33,E2:E33,C2:C33,C2:C33))`) it works fine. The problem is when I change all of the `33` to `34`, therefore entering a new date, it gives `#DIV/0!`.

Please note that in the real data there is more than one `acct_mgr`.

Comment: Are you sure you are changing all the 33’s to 34? If you miss one...

Comment: What is the purpose of `E2:E33,E2:E33,C2:C33,C2:C33`? Both of those are just going to return `True` as they're looking for themselves in themselves...

Comment: @SolarMike yepp, I'm sure.

Comment: @dwirony not sure - was given the formula by someone else. You do have a valid point as far as I can understand though.

Comment: @WolfieeifloW Can you please take a screenshot of your Excel sheet (omitting any private info), showing us where the formula is returning `#DIV/0!` and the formula in the cell?

Comment: @WolfieeifloW The typo looks to be right here `A2:A33,H2,D2:D33,H3` - `H2` for column `A`, then `H3` for column `D`? Highly suspect - me thinks nothing meets that criteria... Equaling zero :)

Comment: @dwirony 33: https://i.imgur.com/a9jptBB.png ... 34: https://i.imgur.com/TUxuoKc.png

Comment: @WolfieeifloW Get rid of the `E2:E34,E2:E34,C2:C34,C2:C34` imo

Comment: @dwirony the SUMPRODUCT causes the criteria to iterate to iterate so in effect it is doing 33 different countifs.  The issue is that the last line the date does not equal the criteria in H3 and thus returns 0 and you cannot divide by 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E2:E34*(A2:A34=H2)*(D2:D34=H3))/(COUNTIFS(A:A,H2,D:D,H3,E:E,E2:E34,C:C,C2:C34)+(A2:A34<>H2)+(D2:D34<>H3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Slapped an `IFERROR` on there too and it works perfectly :) Thank you!! Just for others the full formula is `=SUMIFS(B2:B34,A2:A34,H2,D2:D34,H3)/SUMPRODUCT((E2:E34*(A2:A34=H2)*(D2:D34=H3))/(COUNTIFS(A:A,H2,D:D,H3,E:E,E2:E34,C:C,C2:C34)+(A2:A34<>H2)+(D2:D34<>H3)))`

Comment: I'm not sure what that edit is for? It still gives `#DIV/0!` without `IFERROR`.

Comment: I cannot get the formula to give that error no matter what I do.

Comment: Are you adding in the `=SUMIFS(B2:B34,A2:A34,H2,D2:D34,H3)/` part? The "full" formula in my real data gives `#DIV/0!` if an `acct_mgr` has no data for that particular `date`.

Comment: the only way to error is to have information that does not exist in the table.  Then you get the error and yes then you would need the IFERROR wrapper to take care of when the inputs are in error.  But if the data is in the table, the name and date, then it will not error.  I think I was thinking of something else.  The change was not really needed the more I think on it and I am going to roll back.  I tried to solve a problem that would never exist.